# Http 403 server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-blob-storage

I generated SAS url with below code

```
var blobBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
                Protocol = SasProtocol.Https,
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-2),
                BlobContainerName = _containerName
            };

            var blockBlob = _blobContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName);
            blobBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobAccountSasPermissions.Read);

            var isBlobExist = blockBlob.Exists();
            if (isBlobExist)
            {
                var uriData = blockBlob.GenerateSasUri(blobBuilder);
                if (uriData != null)
                {
                    path = uriData.AbsoluteUri;
                }
            }
```

Generated URI is working most of the time for mobile users but sometimes it returns this error message when trying to download file

> server returned http 403 server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

I am not sure what wrong am I doing here because it works most of the time but doesn't work sometime.
I am also wondering if this is the case when someone try to override the file and other user is trying to read it. Please suggest

Comment: At what point are you getting the error? Is it when a user tries to use the generated sas or is it at blockBlob.Exists() or at blockBlob.GenerateSasUri(blobBuilder)?

Comment: When user is trying to use the generated URI @sr28

Comment: When you try the sas that's been generated that initially gives you a 403, does it always give you a 403 or sometimes work?

Comment: Most of the time it works. and it does not give any error on URI generation, It throws this error when client is trying to download the file from URI @sr28

Comment: Do you have IPs whitelisted on the storage account? Might be they're hitting from a different IP address when it's not working.

Comment: No there is not IP restrictions as of now :(